# terminal fonts on debian 10 (konsole and gnome terminal)

Tags: debian, terminal, fonts, kde

I am on debian 10 (current stable) with kde (`plasmashell --version`  → 5.14.5) . My main terminal emulator is konsole (from KDE). I want support for emojis and other special charecters on the terminal along with a good looking monospace font. I tried the following:

- download and install some fonts from [https://www.nerdfonts.com](https://www.nerdfonts.com/font-downloads)

  - install: unpack the zip-file, opened the font file (`xyz.ttf`) with KFontView and clicked "install font"-button
  - choose this font in profile settings of konsole
- run `python -m rich'

  - this should generate some showcase output like the following [image: show case output of python -m rich]
  - but instead output looks like the following [image: suboptimal show case output of python -m rich]
  - In particular:

    - missing glyphs for asian languages and emojis
    - corrupted boudary box (last section of output)

I also installed the debian package "fonts-noto-color-emoji" from official debian package repo. If I choose this font in konsole profile the missing glyphs appear but the latin characters are hard to read (some serif font) and numbers are even harder to read. This is not an option.